# FFMPEG - creating segments from a single source using segment_times as aposed to -ss

Tags: ffmpeg

I have been successfully creating segments from a single source file using -ss and -t after the -i, using a python script to create a .txt file containing the list of segments and using -concat to mux the segments together.

Today I have discovered -f segments and -segment_times, however I have searched through superuser and google and I cannot find why my command is now working, can anyone help?

I would also like to be able to use the segment_list function however the documentation is not very clear on the syntax that needs to be used.

Here is the command I have been using:

```
C:\Users\3A01>ffmpeg -i f:\Transcoder\repo\LB000001.mp4 -f segment -segment_times 10,20 -c copy -map 0 f:\test.mp4
```

Here is the output:

```
C:\Users\3A01>ffmpeg -i f:\Transcoder\repo\LB000001.mp4 -f segment -segment_times 10,20 -c copy -map 0 f:\test.mp4
ffmpeg version N-82225-gb4e9252 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 5.4.0 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --   enable-dxva2 --enable-libmfx --enable-nvenc --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --   enable-libebur128 --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-   iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --   enable-libfreetype --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenh264 --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --     enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-decklink --enable-zlib
  libavutil      55. 35.100 / 55. 35.100
  libavcodec     57. 66.101 / 57. 66.101
  libavformat    57. 57.100 / 57. 57.100
  libavdevice    57.  2.100 / 57.  2.100
  libavfilter     6. 66.100 /  6. 66.100
  libswscale      4.  3.100 /  4.  3.100
  libswresample   2.  4.100 /  2.  4.100
  libpostproc    54.  2.100 / 54.  2.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'f:\Transcoder\repo\LB000001.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    creation_time   : 2016-03-10T20:46:05.000000Z
    encoder         : HandBrake 0.10.5 2016021100
  Duration: 00:29:43.08, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 869 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv,     smpte170m/bt470bg/bt709), 718x576 [SAR 16:15 DAR 359:270], 703 kb/s, 25 fps, 25    tbr, 90k tbn, 180k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2016-03-10T20:46:05.000000Z
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo,     fltp, 160 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2016-03-10T20:46:05.000000Z
      handler_name    : Stereo
[mp4 @ 0000000000028200] Invalid segment filename template 'f:\test.mp4'
Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?):         Invalid argumentStream mapping:
      Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
      Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (copy)
    Last message repeated 1 times
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`test.mp4` should be `test%d.mp4`. Since you'll be creating multiple files, you need to supply an output name with a pattern that ffmpeg will use to name the multiple files. The one I supplied will produce `test1.mp4` `test2.mp4` ...

Be aware that since you're using copy mode, the cuts may not happen at the precise specified points.

Comment: Thanks! That got it working and opens up more questions, like how do you use segments with in and out points so you can create a conform?

Comment: I don't see an option to set outpoints. What you could try is to include the outpoints in the segment_times list, and then delete every other segment created, starting with the 2nd.